# Using `dynamic` for arbitrary number types

Tags: c#, generics, types, dynamic

I keep having use cases where it would be nice to have a parent `Number` type that the numeric primitives inherit from, but to the best of my research, none exists. The next best solution I've found is using the `dynamic` keyword.

For example, if I want to write a function to double a number, I don't care if that number is an `int` or a `double` as the code will be the same: `return value * 2;`.

My best approximation of this would be using `dynamic` to simply resolve types at runtime and using a `switch` statement to filter types via pattern matching

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double numberD = DoubleNumber(Math.PI);
    float numberF = DoubleNumber((float)Math.PI);
    int numberI = DoubleNumber((int)Math.PI);
}

static T DoubleNumber<T>(T value)
{
    return value switch
    {
        int or float or double => (dynamic)value * 2,
        _ => throw new InvalidCastException(typeof(T).ToString()),
    };
}
```

However, this is still jank since at compile time, literally any type could be sent as input to this function. If a `string` is passed into the function, that will not be caught until runtime.

Is there a way to rewrite my function signature such that it will only take `int`, `uint`, `float`, or `double`, without copy/pasting the backing code into separate functions targeting these types individually?

Comment: A coworker helped me figure this out. What I needed was the `INumber<T>` interface. My question was not duplicate.

Comment: meh, the *intent* is a duplicate; the exact words: sure, but it is the *intent* that matters, mostly